# How to differentiate $y=(x+1)^3/x^{3/2}$ and $y=2x^4/(b^2-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I need to solve a list of derivatives to help me on an exam; however, I'm in doubt when they use another variable (constant) or when I have a fraction with functions that use the power rule.

For example:

$$y = \frac{(x + 1)^3}{x^{3/2}}.$$

This one I tried having $u = x + 1$, deriving it and having $v = x^{3/2}$, but I couldn't get the right answer.

And:

$$y = \frac{2x^4}{b^2 - x^2}.$$

And this one I tried to separate the constant, like $y = \frac{1}{b^2} \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{2x^4}{-x^2}$, but also coudn't find the answer.

Can you give a tip on how to find which rule to apply to these kind of derivatives?

Comment: You cannot separate the constant that way! You must take care of such operative facts.

Comment: @DanielEscudero Haha, reminds me of $$\frac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}=\frac{x-y}{-}=x+y$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really only need the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) and the [power rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule).

For the quotient rule, when $y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ (where $g(x)\neq 0$), we have $y'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$.

**Problem 1:** Differentiate $y = \frac{(x + 1)^3}{x^{3/2}}$ with respect to $x$.

*Solution.* We have $y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f(x)=(x+1)^3$ and $g(x)=x^{3/2}$. Thus, we also have $f'(x)=3(x+1)^2$ and $g'(x)=\frac{3}{2}x^{1/2}$. Using the quotient rule, we see that
$$
y' = \frac{3(x+1)^2\cdot x^{3/2}-(x+1)^3\cdot\frac{3}{2}x^{1/2}}{(x^{3/2})^2}.
$$

**Problem 2:** Differentiate $y = \frac{2x^4}{b^2 - x^2}$ with respect to $x$.

*Solution.* We have $y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f(x)=2x^4$ and $g(x)=b^2-x^2$. Thus, we also have $f'(x)=8x^3$ and $g'(x)=-2x$. Using the quotient rule, we see that
$$
y'=\frac{8x^3\cdot(b^2-x^2)-2x^4\cdot(-2x)}{(b^2-x^2)^2}.
$$

If required, all that is left to do is for you to simplify.

Comment: Excellent. My teacher always places the answer with each problem, and I always had in my mind that the derivative of a constant is 0, so I couldn't understand until now how could the answer keep the constant. Now things are clear. Thank you.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira You're very welcome. I'm glad it makes sense now. :)

Comment: @DanielEscudero Haha. Bandicoot is the best. Ya know what's the worst? You say it... :)

Comment: @crash I always disliked Cortex. Always kidnapping Coco...

Comment: @DanielEscudero Yes! Dr. Neo Cortex. The worst. Bandicooters think alike ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the expression contains products and ratioé, logarithmic differentiation make life much easier.

Let us consider the first problem $$y = \frac{(x + 1)^3}{x^{3/2}}$$ Taking logarithms $$\log(y)=3\log(x+1)-\frac32\log(x)$$ Now, differentiate both sides $$\frac{y'}y=\frac3{x+1}-\frac3{2x}=\frac{3 (x-1)}{2 x (x+1)}$$ $$y'=\frac{3 (x-1)}{2 x (x+1)}y=\frac{3 (x-1)}{2 x (x+1)} \frac{(x + 1)^3}{x^{3/2}}=\frac{3 (x-1) (x+1)^2}{2 x^{5/2}}$$

Do the same for the second problem $$y = \frac{2x^4}{b^2 - x^2}$$ $$\log(y)=\log(2)+4\log(x)-\log(b^2-x^2)$$ $$\frac{y'}y=0+\frac 4x+\frac{2x}{b^2-x^2}=\frac{2(2b^2-x^2)}{x(b^2-x^2)}$$ $$y'=\frac{2(2b^2-x^2)}{x(b^2-x^2)}y=\frac{2(2b^2-x^2)}{x(b^2-x^2)}\frac{2x^4}{b^2 - x^2}=\frac{4(2b^2-x^2)x^3}{(b^2-x^2)^2}$$